# Do I need a developer token to get data from Adwords

Tags: c#, java, google-api, google-ads-api

Do I need a developer token to **get** data from Adwords?

I only want to grab some data and not create/edit/modify something.

My plan was to let my customers authenticate via oauth and then plot some charts over their data from adwords.

It seems to me I have to get a developer key to obtain that data ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151851/do-i-need-a-dev-token-to-access-adwords-api-via-oauth)).

Is this right or is there another way to get data out of an adwords account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is [yes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/mC7mB-YYH-Q), you need a developer token to get data from AdWords:

> A developer token is required to make AdWords API calls. It's main
>   purpose is to ensure that the developer has accepted AdWords API T&Cs,
>   identify your requests in case we need to troubleshoot issues you are
>   facing, etc. In the past, it was also used to identify the account to
>   which API calls were charged, but that's no longer the case since
>   AdWords API calls are now free.
>
> OAuth2 tokens are used to authenticate the calls you make against a
>   client account. You may also use ClientLogin as an alternative to
>   OAuth2, but it is deprecated and it's use is strongly discouraged.
>
> You need an MCC account to get a developer token, but it's not a
>   requirement that the account you make calls to lives under that MCC.
>   Using OAuth, you could make calls to a totally unrelated account (e.g.
>   a client logs in from the UI), as long as you can generate an access
>   token for the same. Right now, your developer token is under review,
>   that's why your ability to make calls are restricted to test accounts.
>   Once your token is approved, you should be able to make calls to any
>   account that you have access to.

Comment: But is there no way to get the data without using the adwords api? For example over the analytics api?

Comment: You have to access each of them separately to get right data. By looking at Analytics and AdWords data side-by-side, you can gain a big-picture perspective that wouldn't be available to you by just looking at one data-set at a time.